# Android Horizontal Scroll View full scroll right doesnt go all the way

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, android-scrollview

```
hsv.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
```

Takes my `HorizontalScrollView` 99% to the right but not 100%, I need to scroll the view all the way to the right. Any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: How have you determined the 99% versus 100% result?

Comment: well, it's not a definite 99% but the view doesn't go all the way, I can manually scroll it further to the right.

Comment: have you found a fix ? I got the same issue. Perhaps due to margin not taken in account by focus ?

Comment: @buzeeg I've added an answer with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by using a `ViewTreeObserver` applied on the `HorizontalScrollView`

An example can be found here:

[Android - HorizontalScrollView will not scroll all the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772632/android-horizontalscrollview-will-not-scroll-all-the-way)